# Modifying project organization with Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I created a project that I initially thought would be simple (few files) but now the project is growing. I'm trying to reorganize the directory structure, but I'm not sure how to modify the makefile.

Here is the structure I have:

```
root_dir
  Makefile
  main.cc
  fileA.cc
  fileA.h
  fileB.cc
  fileB.h
```

Also fileB depends from fileA (`#include "fileA.h"`) and my Makefile looks like this:

```
all: myExec

myExec: main.o fileA.o fileB.o
     g++ -Wall main.o fileA.o fileB.o -o myExec

main.o: main.cc fileA.h fileB.h
     g++ -Wall -c main.cc

fileA.o: fileA.cc fileA.h
     g++ -Wall -c fileA.cc

fileB.o: fileB.cc fileB.h fileA.h
     g++ -Wall -c fileB.cc
```

Now I'd like to have something like that:

```
root_dir
  Makefile
  main.cc
  dirA
    fileA.cc
    fileA.h
  dirB
     fileB.cc
     fileB.h
```

I read that I could create a Makefile in each subdirectory, but I'm not sure this is doable here, because fileB depends on fileA (which is on another subdirectory).

Or should I modify my main Makefile to include subdir ?

Thank you.

Comment: How does your current Makefile work ?

Comment: You'll need to provide a real-world example, how does `fileB` depend on `fileA`? Details such as these are crucial, you haven't even said what you're making, executables? Libraries?

Comment: I added the Makefile description.
I mentionned fileB include fileA (#include 'fileA.h'). I'm creating an executable.

Comment: A while ago I've [answered](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1898/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-un-makefile-que-calcule-las-dependencias/1929#1929) a similar question on Spanish SO. Frankly speaking, you don't need to explicitly specify `.h`-files as dependencies, because gcc can collect this info for you. Check the answer (there's a self-evident Makefile), maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stick to a single makefile it's really not that different from what you are already doing, you just need to set the include flags correctly. Your makefile can also be greatly simplified thanks to make's built-in rules, and with GCC's dependency generation flags you don't need to manually add the headers.

N.b. change `main.cc` to `myExec.cc`, it's more intuitive IMO and allows you to skip the link recipe.

```
srcs := $(wildcard dirA/*.cc dirB/*.cc)
objs := $(srcs:.cc=.o) myExec.o
deps := $(objs:.o=.d)

CPPFLAGS := -MMD -MP

myExec: CC := $(CXX)
myExec: $(objs)
myExec.o: CPPFLAGS += -IdirA -IdirB
dirA/%.o: CPPFLAGS += -IdirB

.PHONY: clean
clean: ; $(RM) $(objs) $(deps) myExec

-include $(deps)
```

That said, it's hard to see what the advantage would be of splitting your project into multiple directories with such an artificial example.

Comment: Thanks. However I find your solution not easy to read. Also it stays pretty simple because it's a simple example I gave, but in reality I have about 10 subdirs, which will complicate the makefile with your solution a lot, isn't it ?

Comment: @whiteShadow It depends, if all you have is other source files for the same executable in those directories then it's as simple as adding the dir to `wildcard`, you should probably think about using the makefile dir as the include root at any rate and do `#include "dirB/fileB.h` etc, that way you don't need to specify separate include directories when compiling.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, thanks. I will have a look at the makefile solution you proposed to better understand it. Thanks.